# Equivocal boundary conditions for Laplace equation of 2D "V"-shape conductor

Tags: electrostatics, boundary-conditions

A two dimensional infinite "V"-shape wedge conductor is earthed, wherein $\beta$ is the intersection angle. We can solve Laplace equation so as to get the electric potential inside the "V" zone, as is shown in the figure. $a_n$'s are actually determined by some other boundary condition far away from origin and we just preserve $a_1$ here. It is noteworthy that we make use of the equipotential condition (the 1st yellow formula), consequently, we have the exponents of $r^\nu$ to be $\nu=\frac{n\pi}{\beta}$.

However, how about adding an additional $2\pi$ periodic boundary condition (which seemes to be physically reasonable here)? If we did it, then the exponents of $r^\nu$ ought to be $\nu=\text{integer}$. The form of solution appears to be rather different from the original one in the figure.

Are they equivalent, or at least equivalent inside the "V" zone? Or is this wrong?

[image]